# Building Pulseaudio WebRTC module for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, pulseaudio

I'm stuck with building WebRTC AudioProcessing module on Raspberry Pi 3:

```
CPPAS signal_processing/libcommon_audio_la-filter_ar_fast_q12_armv7.lo
signal_processing/filter_ar_fast_q12_armv7.S: Assembler messages:
signal_processing/filter_ar_fast_q12_armv7.S:88: Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `sbfx r11,r6,#12,#16'
signal_processing/filter_ar_fast_q12_armv7.S:99: Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `sbfx r11,r6,#12,#16'
signal_processing/filter_ar_fast_q12_armv7.S:142: Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `sbfx r8,r6,#12,#16'
Makefile:921: recipe for target 'signal_processing/libcommon_audio_la-filter_ar_fast_q12_armv7.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [signal_processing/libcommon_audio_la-filter_ar_fast_q12_armv7.lo] Error 1
```

Also a was trying with:

```
./configure CC="gcc -arch armv7" CXX="g++ -arch armv7 " CPP="gcc -E" CXXCPP="g++ -E"
```

Is there any way to get this running?

Comment: The good practice is when you answer your question via answer, rather than updating your question with solution. Please fix this. Note, [you need to wait for 48 hours before you can accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

ok done

```
./configure CFLAGS="-mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4" CXXFLAGS="-mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4"
```